# catalog grid custom filter function is too specific

Tags: catalog, grid, filter, catalogsearch

To my catalog grid ive added an extra column, which contains an attribute value, better said a color value.

Now I added a filter function with a dropdown.

*This one looks like this:*

```
protected function _colorFilter($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $field = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
    $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond["eq"]);
    return $this;
}
```

This works great, except it filters just for the values which are excactly the ones selected. That means: some fields have the value `140`, some `76` and some `33`.

When I select the value for `76`, it gives me all the products wich have the attribute-/color-value `76`. But what I want, are all the products wich have the value `76`, `76,140`, `76,33`, `76,140,33`.

I cannot find any way to perform this. Is this even possible with the function `addFieldToFilter()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested code).
Instead of

```
 $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond["eq"]);
```

You should alter the condition value and change the condition mode.
So.

```
$condition = $cond["eq"];
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, array('finset'=>$condition));
```

In case this does not work, log the value of `$cond["eq"]` and post it in the question.